# Items not following order in HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So if you go to diartefloral.tech and use cellphone dimension in the "Sobre Nosotros" part of the menu the footer is overlapping an image, i dont know how to fix this. Thats like the most relevant code, I'm using bootstrap, i got the in the morning with the navbar overlapping the footer but i fixed it by adding the body{ padding-top:60px;}

```css
.principal{
    background-color: rgb(230,219,241);
}

.container >a{
    font-family: Charmonman, serif;font-size: 35px;padding-bottom: -5px;padding-top: 9px;
}


.site-footer
{
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #7f70f5, #0ea0ff);
  padding:45px 0 20px;
  font-size:15px;
  line-height:24px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
.site-footer hr
{
  border-top-color:#bbb;
  opacity:0.5
}
.site-footer hr.small
{
  margin:20px 0
}
.site-footer h6
{
  color:#fff;
  font-size:16px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-top:5px;
  letter-spacing:2px
}
.site-footer a
{
  color:white;
}
.site-footer a:hover
{
  color:#3366cc;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.footer-links
{
  padding-left:0;
  list-style:none
}
.footer-links li
{
  display:block
}
.footer-links a
{
  color:white;
}
.footer-links a:active,.footer-links a:focus,.footer-links a:hover
{
  color:#3366cc;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.footer-links.inline li
{
  display:inline-block
}
.site-footer .social-icons
{
  text-align:right
}
.site-footer .social-icons a
{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  margin-left:6px;
  margin-right:0;
  border-radius:100%;
  background-color:white
}
.copyright-text
{
  margin:0
}
@media (max-width:991px)
{
  .site-footer [class^=col-]
  {
    margin-bottom:0;
  }
}
@media (max-width:767px)
{
  .site-footer
  {
    padding-bottom:0
  }
  .site-footer .copyright-text,.site-footer .social-icons
  {
    text-align:center
  }
}
.social-icons
{
  padding-left:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  list-style:none
}
.social-icons li
{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:4px
}
.social-icons li.title
{
  margin-right:15px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#96a2b2;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:13px
}
.social-icons a{
  background-color:#eceeef;
  color:#818a91;
  font-size:16px;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:44px;
  width:44px;
  height:44px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:8px;
  border-radius:100%;
  -webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
  -o-transition:all .2s linear;
  transition:all .2s linear
}
.social-icons a:active,.social-icons a:focus,.social-icons a:hover
{
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#29aafe
}
.social-icons.size-sm a
{
  line-height:34px;
  height:34px;
  width:34px;
  font-size:14px
}
.social-icons a.facebook:hover
{
  background-color:#3b5998
}
.social-icons a.instagram:hover
{
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%, #e6683c 25%, #dc2743 50%, #cc2366 75%, #bc1888 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%,#e6683c 25%,#dc2743 50%,#cc2366 75%,#bc1888 100%); 
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%,#e6683c 25%,#dc2743 50%,#cc2366 75%,#bc1888 100%); 
}


@media (max-width:767px)
{
  .social-icons li.title
  {
    display:block;
    margin-right:0;
    font-weight:600
  }
}


@media (max-width: 700px){
    #logo{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .container >button >span{
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 500px){
    #logo{
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .container >button >span{
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
    }
    
}

@media (max-width: 400px){
    #logo{
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    .container >button >span{
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
    }
    
}

@media (max-width: 350px){
    #logo{
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    .container >button >span{
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
    }
    
}
@media (max-width: 300px){
    #logo{
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .container >button >span{
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
    }
    
}

@media (max-width: 250px){
    #logo{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .container >button >span{
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
    }
    
}

.imagen{
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.imagen >img{
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 20px;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../estilos/estilos.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Charmonman&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../estilos/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>DiArteFloral</title>
</head>
<body class="principal">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top bg-white portfolio-navbar gradient navbar-static-top" style="height: 86px;" id="banner">
        <div class="container"><a id='logo' class="navbar-brand logo" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-pagelines"></i>DiArteFloral y Regalos</a><button data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" id="boton"><span class="visually-hidden">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto" id="menu">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="../index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./productos.html">Productos</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./sobreN.html">Sobre Nosotros</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </br>
    <div class="imagen">
      <div class="imagen">
        <img src="../img/LOGO.jpg" alt="LOGO">
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="site-footer">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
              <h6>Informacion</h6>
              <p class="text-justify">DiArteFloral y Regalos es una empresa enfocada en complacer a las personas brindandoles el mejor servicio y los productos mas bonitos que se puedan crear al gusto exclusivo de cada cliente.</p>
            </div>
  
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
              <h6>Categorias</h6>
              <ul class="footer-links">
                <li><a href="">Arreglos</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Eventos</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
  
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
              <h6>Atajos</h6>
              <ul class="footer-links">
                <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Productos</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PSobre Nosotros</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; 2021 All Rights Reserved by 
           <a href="https://www.instagram.com/sergioxcc/">Sergio Calderon</a>.
              </p>
            </div>
  
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <ul class="social-icons">
                <li><a class="facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li> 
                <li><a class="instagram" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </footer>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6a4338d571.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../estilos/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../estilos/theme.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let boton = document.querySelector('#boton');
    let menu = document.querySelector('#banner');
    let logo = document.querySelector('#logo');
    boton.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        if(menu.style.height==='86px'){
            menu.style.height='240px'
        }else{
            menu.style.height='86px'
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not a good approach. Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: Could you show us some code ?

Comment: already added the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User agents will always display items in the DOM order.

You mean customize css properties. I see you are doing great in your live site, try to use images that sizes less than 1.5Mb, it slows rendering visuals.